# Unable to get a response from the backend as to my query. How can I fix this issue?

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-volley

I am trying to create a register activity which uses volley and PHP to connect to mySQL. I have attached some of the code. The code works perfectly fine till i try to get the response back from the Database. While using StringRequest, the control is not entering this section of the code. How can i fix this problem? Please Help.

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String rurl = "http://102.160.2.104/register.php";
String message;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    final EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    ....
    final EditText weig = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight);
    final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

    bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String name = etName.getText().toString();
            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            ...

            if(!(conpassword.equals(password))){
                etPassword.setText("");
                etconpas.setText("");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Passwords don't match",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

//The problem arises over here as it does not enter the onResponse() method.

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, rurl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                        message = jsonObject.getString("message");
                        fin();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        System.out.println("hhellooo");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                private void fin() {
                    System.out.println(message);
                    if(message.equals("User already exists")){
                        etName.setText("");
                        etPassword.setText("");
                        contact.setText("");
                        etUsername.setText("");
                        age.setText("");
                        heig.setText("");
                        weig.setText("");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User already Exists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("name",name);
                    params.put("username",username);
                    params.put("password",password);
                    params.put("value", finalValue);
                    params.put("phone", String.valueOf(phone));
                    params.put("years", String.valueOf(years));
                    params.put("height", String.valueOf(height));
                    params.put("weight", String.valueOf(weight));
                    return params;
                }
            };
            MySingleton.getInstance(RegisterActivity.this).addtoRQ(stringRequest);
        }
    });
}
```

The MySingleton class file to add the request into the queue.

```
class MySingleton {
private static MySingleton mInstance;
private static RequestQueue requestQueue;
private Context context;

private MySingleton(Context ctx) {
    context = ctx;
    requestQueue = getRequestQueue();
}


private RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if(requestQueue==null)
    {
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return requestQueue;
}

static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context con){
    if(mInstance==null)
    {
        mInstance = new MySingleton(con);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

<T>void addtoRQ(Request<T> request) {

    requestQueue.add(request);

}
```

Comment: Can you add a Log.d just after you enter the response callback and print the response text. The same for Failure. Also do you have wireshark or some software to see if your request is being sent?

Answer (score 0):

I think your request is not being sent because you haven't added it to a request queue.

```
RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

// Instantiate the cache
Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024); // 1MB cap

// Set up the network to use HttpURLConnection as the HTTP client.
Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());

// Instantiate the RequestQueue with the cache and network.
mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);

// Start the queue
mRequestQueue.start();

<Your request setup>

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
mRequestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

From: [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html)

Comment: I have used the MySingleton class to add the request to the request queue. I shall add the class file. Please check and let me know.